# Windows equivalent of ulimit -n

Tags: windows, file-descriptor, ulimit

What is the windows equivalent of the unix command " ulimit -n" ?

Basically, i want to set the maximum fd limit via command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... I may have been wrong before - setmaxstdio (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/File_Descriptor_Limit.aspx)) - but it is per-process, not system wide.

<s>I may be wrong, but I didn't think there was a limit to set in Windows...</s> but unless you can say how this relates to programming, I expect this answer will be closed soon.

If you are in the "IT Pro" area (rather than development), then there is a sister-site, serverfault.com - coming soon for this type of question.

Comment: The only limit I know of is more likely related to the maximum number of kernel handles - this seems to be something in the range of 100000, but this allows for all manner of things not including files

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that current Windows O/S have a limit on the *total* number of file descriptors, but the MS runtime library (`msvcrt.dll`) has a *per process* limit of 2048, albeit as far as I know that's not enforced by the O/S.

It can allegedly be increased only by building your own version of the MS runtime library from source.