# Limit to how many files Maya can open on Windows

Tags: windows, maya, ulimit

I've searched for this quite extensively on internet, and often the answer is a question: why do you need so many opened files at the same time?

Actually the program I'm working on is Autodesk Maya 2014, and when you use geometry caches, when you import these geocaches in your scene, maya will open as many files as they are shapes cached. If you add  to this other opened files like textures and references, we found we had a limitation of 507 opened files.

I read that on Linux, it would be as simple as doing ulimit -n, but I can't find any viable solution on Windows to allow Maya to open more than these 507 documents.

Comment: Appears to be a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729162/windows-equivalent-of-ulimit-n

Comment: Windows has a Handle abstraction that applies to all kinds of things, not just files. You might find this page on [Kernel Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724485(v=vs.85).aspx) (which includes file handles) a worthwhile read.

Comment: thanks for the link and the read. checking them out right now.

Comment: so for the link to the other stackoverflow question, I followed the setmaxstdio link, and indeed that program manages to change the limit from 512 to 2048, but I have no idea how I can do the same in Maya, which I'm not going to compile! For the link about Kernel Handles, it's quite interesting, but it won't help much to solve the initial problem (understanding it better, yes. Solving it, no)

Comment: [The theoretical limit is around 16 million](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/19/3283844.aspx). But your runtime library may have a lower limit.

Comment: yes it does. 512 on our systems at work. You can be running python interpreter, a shell, maya, or photoshop, all of them are limited to 512. If there's python in the app (like for maya), and you manage to have pywin32 in the app, the trick in the solution will work.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to find a solution for this.
First, I found precompiled versions of pywin32 for maya here:
http://www.cnblogs.com/jonn/p/3829575.html

Then, simply typing this:

```
import win32file
print win32file._getmaxstdio() #512
win32file._setmaxstdio(2048)
print win32file._getmaxstdio() #2048
```

voila!